Golang buildmode CShared, Problem with delegate func, How to Load it
tried for create simple function callback in cshared with golang
package main

import "C"
import "fmt"

//export Callback
type Callback func()

//export CallbackEvent
func CallbackEvent(fn Callback) {
    fn()
}

//export SumFunc
type SumFunc func(C.int, C.int) C.int

//export SumEvent
func SumEvent(fn SumFunc) {
    var out C.int = fn(1, 2)
    res := int(out)
    fmt.Println(res)
}

//export Sum
func Sum(a, b C.int) C.int {
    return a + b
}

but in result build, i got it
/* End of boilerplate cgo prologue.  */

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

extern __declspec(dllexport) void CallbackEvent(void* fn);
extern __declspec(dllexport) void SumEvent(void* fn);
extern __declspec(dllexport) int Sum(int a, int b);
extern __declspec(dllexport) void enforce_binding();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

it really work? my first time interest about cshared in golang
try build into cshared, and no warning message, i want it nicely import golang with ffi, but i'm not expected it really work well
what i'm not expected is void*, make me hard todo something like that
now im simple tried in program dart, and csharp C#
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'lib/generated_bindings.dart';

final NativeLibrary lib = NativeLibrary(DynamicLibrary.open('lib/example.dll'));

typedef Callback = Void Function();

void Test() {
  print("Callback Invoked!");
}

void main() {
  print(lib.Sum(1, 2));
  final CallbackPtr = Pointer.fromFunction<Callback>(Test);
  final VoidPtr = Pointer<Void>.fromAddress(CallbackPtr.address);
  lib.CallbackEvent(VoidPtr);
}

yeah, im using ffigen for shorty impl using native library for dart usage
$env:CGO_ENABLED="1"
$env:GOOS="windows"
$env:GOARCH="amd64"
$env:CC="C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\gcc.exe"

go build -trimpath -buildmode=c-shared -o build/lib/example.dll lib.go
dart run ffigen --config .\ffigen.yaml

the ffigen config like that, (default)
name: NativeLibrary
description: Bindings to `lib/example.h`.
output: 'lib/generated_bindings.dart'
headers:
  entry-points:
    - 'lib/example.h'
preamble: |
  // ignore_for_file: always_specify_types
  // ignore_for_file: camel_case_types
  // ignore_for_file: non_constant_identifier_names
  // ignore_for_file: unused_field
  // ignore_for_file: unused_element
comments:
  style: any
  length: full

what i got it from log after run ffigen, maybe broken or something
Running in Directory: 'C:\Users\n00b\GolandProjects\GoNative\sample_dart_test_case'
Input Headers: [.\lib\example.h]
[WARNING]: No definition found for declaration - (Cursor) spelling: __crt_locale_data, kind: 2, kindSpelling: StructDecl, type: 105, typeSpelling: struct __crt_locale_data, usr: c:@S@__crt_locale_data
[WARNING]: No definition found for declaration - (Cursor) spelling: __crt_locale_data, kind: 2, kindSpelling: StructDecl, type: 105, typeSpelling: struct __crt_locale_data, usr: c:@S@__crt_locale_data        
[WARNING]: No definition found for declaration - (Cursor) spelling: __crt_multibyte_data, kind: 2, kindSpelling: StructDecl, type: 105, typeSpelling: struct __crt_multibyte_data, usr: c:@S@__crt_multibyte_data
[WARNING]: No definition found for declaration - (Cursor) spelling: __crt_multibyte_data, kind: 2, kindSpelling: StructDecl, type: 105, typeSpelling: struct __crt_multibyte_data, usr: c:@S@__crt_multibyte_data
[WARNING]: Removed All Struct Members from _C_ldouble_complex(_C_ldouble_complex), struct member has an unsupported type.
[WARNING]: Skipped Function 'cabsl', Incomplete struct pass/return by value not supported.
[WARNING]: Skipped Function 'cacosl', Incomplete struct pass/return by value not supported.
[WARNING]: Skipped Function 'cacoshl', Incomplete struct pass/return by value not supported.
[WARNING]: Skipped Function 'cargl', Incomplete struct pass/return by value not supported.
[WARNING]: Skipped Function 'casinl', Incomplete struct pass/return by value not supported.
[WARNING]: Skipped Function 'casinhl', Incomplete struct pass/return by value not supported.
[WARNING]: Skipped Function 'catanl', Incomplete struct pass/return by value not supported.
[WARNING]: Skipped Function 'catanhl', Incomplete struct pass/return by value not supported.
[WARNING]: Skipped Function 'ccosl', Incomplete struct pass/return by value not supported.
[WARNING]: Skipped Function 'ccoshl', Incomplete struct pass/return by value not supported.
[WARNING]: Skipped Function 'cexpl', Incomplete struct pass/return by value not supported.
[WARNING]: Skipped Function 'cimagl', Incomplete struct pass/return by value not supported.
[WARNING]: Skipped Function 'clogl', Incomplete struct pass/return by value not supported.
[WARNING]: Skipped Function 'clog10l', Incomplete struct pass/return by value not supported.
[WARNING]: Skipped Function 'conjl', Incomplete struct pass/return by value not supported.
[WARNING]: Skipped Function 'cpowl', Incomplete struct pass/return by value not supported.
[WARNING]: Skipped Function 'cprojl', Incomplete struct pass/return by value not supported.
[WARNING]: Skipped Function 'creall', Incomplete struct pass/return by value not supported.
[WARNING]: Skipped Function 'csinl', Incomplete struct pass/return by value not supported.
[WARNING]: Skipped Function 'csinhl', Incomplete struct pass/return by value not supported.
[WARNING]: Skipped Function 'csqrtl', Incomplete struct pass/return by value not supported.
[WARNING]: Skipped Function 'ctanl', Incomplete struct pass/return by value not supported.
[WARNING]: Skipped Function 'ctanhl', Incomplete struct pass/return by value not supported.
[WARNING]: Skipped Function 'norml', Incomplete struct pass/return by value not supported.
[WARNING]: Skipped Function '_LCbuild', Incomplete struct pass/return by value not supported.
[WARNING]: Skipped Function '_LCmulcc', Incomplete struct pass/return by value not supported.
[WARNING]: Skipped Function '_LCmulcr', Incomplete struct pass/return by value not supported.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '__va_start' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '__security_init_cookie' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '__security_check_cookie' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '__report_gsfailure' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '__security_cookie' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_invalid_parameter_noinfo' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_invalid_parameter_noinfo_noreturn' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_invoke_watson' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '__crt_locale_data_public' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '__crt_locale_pointers' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '__crt_locale_data' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '__crt_multibyte_data' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_Mbstatet' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_errno' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_set_errno' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_get_errno' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '__threadid' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '__threadhandle' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_GoString_' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_C_double_complex' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_C_float_complex' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_C_ldouble_complex' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_Dcomplex' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_Fcomplex' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_Cbuild' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_Cmulcc' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_Cmulcr' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_FCbuild' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_FCmulcc' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_FCmulcr' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_VCRT_COMPILER_PREPROCESSOR' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_SAL_VERSION' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '__SAL_H_VERSION' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_USE_DECLSPECS_FOR_SAL' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_USE_ATTRIBUTES_FOR_SAL' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_CRT_PACKING' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_VCRUNTIME_DISABLED_WARNINGS' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_HAS_EXCEPTIONS' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_WCHAR_T_DEFINED' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_HAS_CXX17' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_HAS_CXX20' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_HAS_CXX23' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_HAS_NODISCARD' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_ARM_WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP_SDK_AVAILABLE' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_CRT_BUILD_DESKTOP_APP' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_UCRT_DISABLED_WARNINGS' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_ARGMAX' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_TRUNCATE' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_CRT_INT_MAX' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_CRT_SIZE_MAX' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '__FILEW__' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_CRT_FUNCTIONS_REQUIRED' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_CRT_HAS_CXX17' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_CRT_HAS_C11' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_CRT_INTERNAL_NONSTDC_NAMES' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '__STDC_SECURE_LIB__' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '__GOT_SECURE_LIB__' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '__STDC_WANT_SECURE_LIB__' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_SECURECRT_FILL_BUFFER_PATTERN' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_CRT_SECURE_CPP_OVERLOAD_STANDARD_NAMES' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_CRT_SECURE_CPP_OVERLOAD_STANDARD_NAMES_COUNT' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_CRT_SECURE_CPP_OVERLOAD_SECURE_NAMES' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_CRT_SECURE_CPP_OVERLOAD_STANDARD_NAMES_MEMORY' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
[WARNING]: Generated declaration '_CRT_SECURE_CPP_OVERLOAD_SECURE_NAMES_MEMORY' starts with '_' and therefore will be private.
Finished, Bindings generated in C:\Users\n00b\GolandProjects\GoNative\sample_dart_test_case\.\lib\generated_bindings.dart

after that, i'm run dart script, get output like that
> dart run .\main.dart
3
unexpected fault address 0xffffffffffffffff
fatal error: fault
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0xffffffffffffffff pc=0x7fff31839c90]

goroutine 17 gp=0xc00006a380 m=1 mp=0xc000076008 [running, locked to thread]:
runtime.throw({0x7fff3186a250?, 0xc00006a380?})
        runtime/panic.go:1023 +0x65 fp=0xc000073e00 sp=0xc000073dd0 pc=0x7fff317e4f05
runtime.sigpanic()
        runtime/signal_windows.go:414 +0xd0 fp=0xc000073e48 sp=0xc000073e00 pc=0x7fff317f8fd0
main.CallbackEvent(...)
        ./lib.go:11
_cgoexp_cece72054328_CallbackEvent(0x7fff317f0b3e?)
        _cgo_gotypes.go:44 +0x10 fp=0xc000073e58 sp=0xc000073e48 pc=0x7fff31839c90
runtime.cgocallbackg1(0x7fff31839c80, 0xf4ae6fedd8, 0x0)
        runtime/cgocall.go:403 +0x2b1 fp=0xc000073f18 sp=0xc000073e58 pc=0x7fff317b5a51
runtime.cgocallbackg(0x7fff31839c80, 0xf4ae6fedd8, 0x0)
        runtime/cgocall.go:322 +0x133 fp=0xc000073f90 sp=0xc000073f18 pc=0x7fff317b56f3
runtime.cgocallbackg(0x7fff31839c80, 0xf4ae6fedd8, 0x0)
        <autogenerated>:1 +0x2e fp=0xc000073fb8 sp=0xc000073f90 pc=0x7fff3181724e
runtime.cgocallback(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        runtime/asm_amd64.s:1079 +0xec fp=0xc000073fe0 sp=0xc000073fb8 pc=0x7fff3181272c
runtime.goexit({})
        runtime/asm_amd64.s:1695 +0x1 fp=0xc000073fe8 sp=0xc000073fe0 pc=0x7fff318129a1

goroutine 2 gp=0xc00006a700 m=nil [force gc (idle)]:
runtime.gopark(0x0?, 0x0?, 0x0?, 0x0?, 0x0?)
        runtime/proc.go:402 +0xce fp=0xc00006dfa8 sp=0xc00006df88 pc=0x7fff317e7c2e
runtime.goparkunlock(...)
        runtime/proc.go:408
runtime.forcegchelper()
        runtime/proc.go:326 +0xb8 fp=0xc00006dfe0 sp=0xc00006dfa8 pc=0x7fff317e7ab8
runtime.goexit({})
        runtime/asm_amd64.s:1695 +0x1 fp=0xc00006dfe8 sp=0xc00006dfe0 pc=0x7fff318129a1
created by runtime.init.6 in goroutine 1
        runtime/proc.go:314 +0x1a

goroutine 3 gp=0xc00006aa80 m=nil [GC sweep wait]:
runtime.gopark(0x0?, 0x0?, 0x0?, 0x0?, 0x0?)
        runtime/proc.go:402 +0xce fp=0xc00006ff80 sp=0xc00006ff60 pc=0x7fff317e7c2e
runtime.goparkunlock(...)
        runtime/proc.go:408
runtime.bgsweep(0xc00007a000)
        runtime/mgcsweep.go:278 +0x94 fp=0xc00006ffc8 sp=0xc00006ff80 pc=0x7fff317d2af4
runtime.gcenable.gowrap1()
        runtime/mgc.go:203 +0x25 fp=0xc00006ffe0 sp=0xc00006ffc8 pc=0x7fff317c7605
runtime.goexit({})
        runtime/asm_amd64.s:1695 +0x1 fp=0xc00006ffe8 sp=0xc00006ffe0 pc=0x7fff318129a1
created by runtime.gcenable in goroutine 1
        runtime/mgc.go:203 +0x66

goroutine 4 gp=0xc00006ac40 m=nil [GC scavenge wait]:
runtime.gopark(0xc00007a000?, 0x7fff3188ba70?, 0x1?, 0x0?, 0xc00006ac40?)
        runtime/proc.go:402 +0xce fp=0xc000085f78 sp=0xc000085f58 pc=0x7fff317e7c2e
runtime.goparkunlock(...)
        runtime/proc.go:408
runtime.(*scavengerState).park(0x7fff318fd680)
        runtime/mgcscavenge.go:425 +0x49 fp=0xc000085fa8 sp=0xc000085f78 pc=0x7fff317d04e9
runtime.bgscavenge(0xc00007a000)
        runtime/mgcscavenge.go:653 +0x3c fp=0xc000085fc8 sp=0xc000085fa8 pc=0x7fff317d0a7c
runtime.gcenable.gowrap2()
        runtime/mgc.go:204 +0x25 fp=0xc000085fe0 sp=0xc000085fc8 pc=0x7fff317c75a5
runtime.goexit({})
        runtime/asm_amd64.s:1695 +0x1 fp=0xc000085fe8 sp=0xc000085fe0 pc=0x7fff318129a1
created by runtime.gcenable in goroutine 1
        runtime/mgc.go:204 +0xa5

goroutine 19 gp=0xc00008c380 m=nil [finalizer wait]:
runtime.gopark(0xc000071e48?, 0x7fff317bdf85?, 0xa8?, 0x1?, 0xc00006a000?)
        runtime/proc.go:402 +0xce fp=0xc000071e20 sp=0xc000071e00 pc=0x7fff317e7c2e
runtime.runfinq()
        runtime/mfinal.go:194 +0x107 fp=0xc000071fe0 sp=0xc000071e20 pc=0x7fff317c6687
runtime.goexit({})
        runtime/asm_amd64.s:1695 +0x1 fp=0xc000071fe8 sp=0xc000071fe0 pc=0x7fff318129a1
created by runtime.createfing in goroutine 1
        runtime/mfinal.go:164 +0x3d

you see, the first function correctly working well, but callback event doesn't work /(0-0)/
i tried using csharp C#, using anaconda3 CS Kernel for this one moment
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

unsafe 
{
[DllImport(@"C:\Users\n00b\GolandProjects\GoNative\sample_dart_test_case\lib\example.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern void CallbackEvent(void* cb);

static void CallbackTest() {
    Console.WriteLine("Callback Invoked!");
}

IntPtr CallbackPtr = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(CallbackTest);
CallbackEvent((void*)CallbackPtr);
}

what i got it from this output (Popup currently) like that
The kernel for Desktop/Concepts Virtual Memory Object Binary Tree/csharp_jupyter_notebook/csharp_load_library.ipynb appears to have died. It will restart automatically.

/(0-0)/ I don't have any idea to load it, or something wrong with my implementation, if u have the answer, make me list too about datatype primitive for the future like
func Message() string { // handle string in C
    // ...
}

type Bytes []byte

func Buffer() Bytes { // handle bytes in C
    // ...
}

/(0-0)/ help me Senpai!

Why not simply try it? If it works then you probably did it all correct and right. If not then ask about the problems you get.

because i dont have any idea to load it, :)

So your question really is "how to load it"? Please [edit] your question to give us more details, like what you're really trying to do, and the problems you have.

I'm with @Someprogrammerdude: the fact you've written this code in Go is (almost) irrelevant. You got a DLL file as a result. So it appears you're asking how to load it. Load where? I mean, what do you want to do with that DLL? You should first answer this question for yourself; once you have an answer, you should try to implement that yourself, and if/when you will fail at that, you return with a question about that specific problem–see this.

@kostix i tried my best, i'm sorry about not trying about load it, but thanks for the advice
